# Flatlist scrollToOffset do not scroll at negative values instead it scroll to the top

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a custom pull to refresh indicator using a Flatlist at some point i need the list to scroll at negative position to show the indicator at the top but scrollToOffset scrolls me to the top instead to y = 0

```
    handleRelease() {
        if (this.state.readyToRefresh) {
            this.flatList.scrollToOffset({ offset: -130 });
        }
    }


      <FlatList
          ref={(flatList: any) => {
              this.flatList = flatList;
          }}
          data={this.props.data}
          renderItem={renderRowItem}
          onScroll={this.handleScroll}
          onResponderRelease={this.handleRelease}
          scrollEventThrottle={16}
      />
```

Non-negative values seems working fine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out you need to set scrollToOverflowEnabled to true to apply this behavior

[ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview)

> When true, the scroll view can be programmatically scrolled beyond its
>   content size. The default value is false.

Comment: How do you set that on the FlatList?