# Scrolling React Native FlatList to negative offset

Tags: javascript, react-native, scroll, react-native-flatlist

I have a `FlatList` and I'm implementing a custom pull to refresh, and the idea is to scroll it to a negative offset to reveal the animation underneath it upon release. Here's the code for my `FlatList`.

```
const flatListRef = useRef(null);

const handleRelease = () => {
    flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({ y: -100 });
    setTimeout(() => {
        flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({ y: 0 });
    }, 1000)
}

return (
    <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onResponderRelease={handleRelease}
        ref={flatListRef}
    />  
)
```

Upon releasing, the `FlatList` should scroll to offset -100 to reveal the animation underneath, and then scrolls back up after 1 second. But what's happening is that it is scrolling to offset 0 (I could tell because I tried scrolling down immediately upon releasing, it will immediately try to scroll back up).

Is it possible to programmatically scroll the `FlatList` to a negative offset?

Answer (score 5):

It looks you need to set scrollToOverflowEnabled to true to apply this behavior.

[ScrollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#__docusaurus)(Flatlist inherits ScrollView Props )

PS:
Here is a different idea.
Maybe you can add a fixed height View if you wanna go to -100. (looks same)
And after time set the view close. (back to origin position?)
(If it doesn't work....)

------------------edit-----

```
<FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{item}</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onResponderRelease={handleRelease}
        ref={flatListRef}
        scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}  // Just put in here 
    />
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like you copied the StackOverflow answer from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58157436/flatlist-scrolltooffset-do-not-scroll-at-negative-values-instead-it-scroll-to-th

I'm not too sure how that solution will work on a FlatList. If you can explain further that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: `scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}` Adding this line to `FlatList` doesn't work.

Comment: It seems only ios have this props, are you build on Android?

Answer (score 1):

Use **offset** instead of **y** as the parameter key for scrollToOffset as stated in [the docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#scrolltooffset):

```
flatlistRef.current.scrollToOffset({ offset: -100 });
```